# ElasticSearch - Search by IP[regex]

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have Kibana and ES. I have many indexes. I am using message field in ElasticSearch. My goal is to mask all IP addresses, which I already do using Logstash.

Now, given the fact there are many different indexes, and also different log types, I would like to run either Kibana or ES query for any occurence of IP. Just in case, that I missed any of them. Also, I would like to do it for email format as well.

Question is, how can I run IP/email regex search on ElasticSearch or Kibana?

Message field is string type, and is indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found what I was looking for. In my case this approach is valid, since I do not care about performance. This was just a test to make sure I don't 'leak' information.

[ElasticSearch regex query.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html)